# angular.js $http.error no status return json

Tags: json, angularjs, http, status

I am new with Angular.js, and I am following the tutorial of the angular website.

I am trying to get my data from a json file with the $http service, **but nothing happens!!
Even the status of the error is not working...**

Here is my code:

```
 <li>{{status}}</li>

 <ul class="messages">
      <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
            {{message.title}}
            <p>{{message.title2}} {{message.icon}}</p>    
      </li>
 </ul>
```

and the js part:

```
var monitorControllers = angular.module('monitorControllers', []);

monitorControllers.controller('MonitorCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('data/messages.json').success(function(data, status) {
       $scope.status = status;
       $scope.messages = data;
   }).error(function(data, status) {
           $scope.messages = data || "Request failed";
           $scope.status = status;
       });    

}]);
```

## **THE SOLUTION :**

Thank you sylwester, I found the problem but it is really strange. So I just added in my js file, this:
(at the beginning and the end..)

```
(function () {
    var monitorControllers = angular.module('monitorControllers', []);

    monitorControllers.controller('MonitorCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get('data/messages.json').success(function(data, status) {
             $scope.status = status;
             $scope.messages = data;
             }).error(function(data, status) {
             $scope.messages = data || "Request failed";
             $scope.status = status;
             });


        }]);
})();
```

Comment: do you have `ng-controller='MonitorCtrl'` in your `HTML` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More likely you missed something please see there :http://jsbin.com/canuma/1/edit?html,js,output

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="monitorControllers">
  <div ng-controller="MonitorCtrl">
   <li>{{status}} {{messages}}</li>

 <ul class="messages">
      <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
            {{message.title}}
            <p>{{message.title2}} {{message.icon}}</p>    
      </li>
 </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var monitorControllers = angular.module('monitorControllers', []);

monitorControllers.controller('MonitorCtrl', function($scope, $http){

  $http.get('data/messages.json').success(function(data, status) {
       $scope.status = status;
       $scope.messages = data;
   }).error(function(data, status) {
           $scope.messages = data || "Request failed";
           $scope.status = status;
       });  


});
```

Comment: Solution in the question!